# Standard deviation of several average±sd

Tags: standard-error

After years of uncertainty, I need to make this question.

I have a conducted several experiments with X replicates each.

I obtain then a dataset, where each "observation" is a single experiment and the values are each average±SD of those replicates.

Now I need to calculate the Average and SD of the whole study.

While it is easy for the mean, Which is the mean of the averages, I don't know how to measure the final SD, including the original error.

Do I need to use some sort of formula of propagation error?

Comment: "Now I need to calculate the Average and SD of the whole study." - do you mean the estimate of the population standard deviation? Or do you mean the standard error on the mean which is our measure of uncertainty on what the value of the mean is?

Comment: Sorry. I meant to calculate the standard error of the mean (SE), which is an estimate of the uncertainty on the mean value across different experiments. Initially I thought to measure again the standard deviation (SD), which however, I now understand it measures the variability of values within a single experiment (as I did in the first step). Can you confirm if the formula for SE is = √[(sumSD^2)/n], where SD is the SD of each experiement and n is the sample size (number of experiments)?

I have also heard about the error propagation. I do not understand if formula can be used in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are [error propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Linear_combinations) formulae available. This is technically just a version of the variance formula for linear combinations of random variables.

First, to clarify some language. We are trying to calculate the estimate of the mean, and the standard error on the mean (not the SD), by aggregating the means of each experiment.

The simplest method is assuming your $n$ experiments are independent. Let's say we have experimental means which are $\bar Y_1, \cdots, \bar Y_n$, each deriving from $X$ observations. Then the variance of the overall mean $\bar Y = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i$

$$
\text{var}(\bar Y) = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n \text{var}(\bar Y_i)
$$

where $\text{var}(\bar Y_i) = s^2_i/X$.

The standard error of $\bar Y$ is the square root of the variance $\sqrt{\text{var}(\bar Y)}$.

Note - taking the overall mean $\bar Y = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i$ is only valid/useful, in my opinion, if you have the same amount of observations  in each experiment. Which you do in this case.